# iOS: How to queue an upload when offline similar to email app

Tags: ios, background, upload, offline

I'm currently updating an app that I didn't build but have been working with for a little while, keep in mind I'm very new to iOS programming. The app uploads work orders to a client server when they are completed using NSURLConnection, if it has no connection it will queue them up and then wait for a connection to do the upload. This is fine unless the app is backgrounded, as often times the user will forget to open the app back up to complete the upload.

Apples email app doesn't have this problem, it will complete uploads even while the app is backgrounded if it finds a connection and notifies the user with that whoosh sound. I'm not sure how that is done in the background as Apple seems to prevent most actions when backgrounded. Is something like that possible using NSURLConnection or will I need to convert everything to use NSURLSession or something similar?

I don't see this topic coming up on google so I'm wondering if somebody could point me in a helpful direction. Thanks!

Comment: you should read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html